# Accepting PayPal payments using the Recurly API

Tags: paypal, recurly

We use the RecurlyAPI.  Currently PayPal payments are only available with the Recurly Hosted Payment Pages and Recurly.js.  Are there any plans to make PayPal payments available through the API?

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently something we're have plans to support, but I'll certainly note it as a request for functionality. You can read more about using PayPal with Recurly [here](https://docs.recurly.com/payment-gateways/paypal-payments#limitations)

Comment: Sorry, but my first question was wrong!  We are currently using Recurly.js v2 ( and going to upgrade to v3 ), and not the RecurlyAPI.  Without using the Hosted Payment Pages how can we accept PayPal payments?

Comment: It's absolutely possible to accept PayPal payments without hosted payment pages. Check out the docs here: https://docs.recurly.com/js/#paypal

You can also look at an example of how to do this here:
https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js-examples/blob/master/public/paypal/index.html